# Implementing custom stopping metrics to optimize during training in H2O model directly from R

Tags: r, customization, package, random-forest, h2o

I'm trying to implement the [`FBeta_Score()`](https://github.com/yanyachen/MLmetrics/blob/master/R/Classification.R) of the `MLmetrics` [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MLmetrics/index.html):

```
FBeta_Score <- function(y_true, y_pred, positive = NULL, beta = 1) {
   Confusion_DF <- ConfusionDF(y_pred, y_true)
   if (is.null(positive) == TRUE) 
   positive <- as.character(Confusion_DF[1,1])
   Precision <- Precision(y_true, y_pred, positive)
   Recall <- Recall(y_true, y_pred, positive)
   Fbeta_Score <- (1 + beta^2) * (Precision * Recall) / (beta^2 * Precision + 
   Recall)
   return(Fbeta_Score)
 }
```

in the [H2O distributed random forest model](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html) and I want to optimize it during the training phase using the `custom_metric_func` option.
The help documentation of the `h2o.randomForest()` function says:

> Reference to custom evaluation function, format:
>   'language:keyName=funcName'

But I don't understand how to use it directly from R and what I should specify in the `stopping_metric` option.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there is only backend support for Python-based custom functions, which can be uploaded to the backend via the [h2o.upload_custom_metric()](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html#h2o.upload_custom_metric) function. This function will then return a function reference (this is a string that has a naming convention format of `'language:keyName=funcName'`). That you can then pass to the `custom_metric` parameter.

For example:

```
custom_mm_func = h2o.upload_custom_metric(CustomRmseFunc, func_name="rmse", func_file="mm_rmse.py")
```

returns a function reference which has the following value:

```
> print(custom_mm_func)
python:rmse=mm_rmse.CustomRmseFuncWrapper
```

As for your second question about using the custom metric as a stopping metric, there is a jira ticket that you can follow here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5261

You can find more details on how to use the custom metric [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/dev/custom_functions.md).