# R h2o: how to implement a custom stopping_metric for GBM

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o

I found out that it is now possible to use `stopping_metric = custom` in `h2o v3.22.1.1` (wasn't available in `v3.10.0.9`), however I didn't find anywhere how to implement it in R.

this is a toy version of the problem.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
x <- data.frame(
   x = rnorm(1000),
   z = rnorm(1000), 
   y = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = T))
)
train <- as.h2o(x)
h2o.gbm(x = c('x','z'), y = 'y', training_frame = train, stopping_metric = 'custom', stopping_rounds = 3)
```

the error I get is the following:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Illegal argument(s) for GBM model: GBM_model_R_1548836369139_123.  Details: ERRR on field: _stopping_metric: Custom metric function needs to be defined in order to use it for early stopping.
```

how can I define the `custom` `stopping_metric` for the GBM?

Comment: Did you saw this : [Implementing custom stopping metrics to optimize during training in H2O model directly from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657527/implementing-custom-stopping-metrics-to-optimize-during-training-in-h2o-model-di)

Comment: yes @MrSmithGoesToWashington but maybe it is now possible to implement it in R, considering that the option was added only recently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing custom stopping metrics to optimize during training in H2O model directly from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657527/implementing-custom-stopping-metrics-to-optimize-during-training-in-h2o-model-di)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently available from the R API. If this is functionality you are interested in I would create a JIRA with your use case [here](http://jira.h2o.ai). You can use the other [SO question Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657527/implementing-custom-stopping-metrics-to-optimize-during-training-in-h2o-model-di) pointed to, for information on how to use this functionality through the Python API.

Comment: I may get this wrong, but this feature is already raised and resolved: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5261?jql=text%20~%20%22custom%20metric%22

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu the issue was resolved for the python api but not for the r api, the original question is not that the functionality exists  - it does - the question was whether it was accessible for the R api - which it is not.

Comment: ah, thanks for clarifying this, and guess this is un-resolved one is the one we can keep an eye on: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4076?jql=text%20~%20%22custom%20metric%22